# how to prevent pandas psql.read_sql_query from fetching cache

Tags: python, pandas

i use pandas 0.15.2 and read from a mysql storedproc into dataframe

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
cnx= pymysql.connect( .. connection string ...)
df=psql.read_sql_query('call storedproc', con=cnx)
```

the database is quite active with new data frequently, I realise whenever i rerun the above statements to load the data into my dataframe, it returns the last queried data cache. if i rerun the read_sql_query a few more times, it does get loaded eventually.
My question is what is the right way to ensure it never get previously cached data?

Comment: It's important to note that pandas itself does not cache anything.

Answer (score 4):

after some testing, i added `autocommit=True` in the connection parameters and it stop fetching cached results even if I am only doing a read. Hope this help others.

Answer (score 1):

I was using MySQLDB for connection and somehow `con.autocommit = True` did not work. So ended up calling `con.commit()` after each read and that fixed the issue. After that each query results in latest data.

Comment: @rene, I had the same problem and con.commit() helped. thans=s